# jQuery: trying to animate all <img> in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following this official jQuery example in the documentation:

[image]

https://api.jquery.com/animate/

I try to apply similar use of the `animate()` function but I would like to subtract three hundred pixels, but *from the current `left` property of each image*.

I have tried the following:

```
$( ".instagram_grid .first" ).animate({
left: $(this img).left -300 
}
```

and then use the step function exactly as in the example, expecting it to apply this same relatively defined `left` property of each image.

However it isn't valid jQuery, or rather, it doesn't actually have any recognizable effect.

Here is my Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/dueq09r6/5/

Comment: Can you use the `margin-left` property instead?  Using `left` can be done but you have to deal with the fact that it can be set to `auto` which is NaN.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you (untested code):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.instagram_grid .first').each(function() {
         $(this).animate({left: $(this).left - 300}, 1000);
    });
});
```

?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your JSFiddle before answering, my bad :)

Comment: it would be better written $('.instagram_grid').find('.first') ;)

Comment: @whitebox Thanks for pointing that out. I've always been struggling with either `$('div > span')` or `$('div').find('span')`, do you have some links that explain this?

Comment: Many thanks! This was clear enough! However, does that work it `id`s only? My previous comment was referencing to the DOM by the `tag` name. What about with `class`?

Comment: Yes it will work for classes, its still more performant than finding every span in a page, then return the one(s) in your container, ID just ensures its restricted to one element

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things - the image's left position returned auto like mentioned before. Then $(this img) should be $(this).find('img') and the value from it's position should be parsed as an integer :

https://jsfiddle.net/dueq09r6/8/

```
$( ".instagram_grid .first" ).animate({
left: parseInt($(this).find('img').css('left'))-300
},
```

Comment: i appreciate this. however, it appears that your implementation, while looking like it would subtract from the extant left, just makes all the divs uniformly left:-300px.

Comment: I see - the each method would then indeed be the better option. Some of the remarks are still valid though so I'll leave the answer in place then.